# Duvida de Symfony2.16

Tags: symfony-2

estou a trbalhar com symfony2.16 pretendo selecionar a pessoa se este nao for chave estrageira na tabela user meu codigo est assim:
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

```
    $idPessoa =  $options['idPessoa'];

    $builder
        ->add('idPessoa', 'entity', array('class' => 'SUGASugaBundle:Pessoa',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)  use ($idPessoa){

                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->join('SUGASugaBundle:User','u')
                    ->where('a.id != u.idPessoa')
                    ->andwhere('a.id != :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $idPessoa)
                    ->orderBy('a.nome');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'getNomeCompleto'
        ))
        ->remove('plainPassword')
        ->remove('username')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' =>'Salvar'));
    ;
```

assim ele esta a trazer quem ja tem conta user